# Get rating data of a facebook page using fb api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get the ratings of a facebook page. However, my code is not working .. i have included the access token also as it needs a page access token and my code isn't right i know.

Here is the code:

```js
FB.login(function(){
  FB.api('/' + my_p_id, {
    fields: 'id, accessToken'
  }, function (response) {
    var p_accessToken = response.data[i].access_token;
    FB.api(
      '/' + my_p_id,
      'GET',
      {'access_token': p_accessToken},
      {"fields":"id,name,ratings{rating}"},
      function(response) {
        if(!response || response.error){
          alert("Error consoled");
          console.log(response.error);
        } else{
          alert("response logged in console");
          console.log(response); 
        }
      }
    );
  }
        );
});
```

Its not alerting anything which means there gotta be something wrong and its not even reaching the alert code i guess. Help me fix my code!